# How can I print something on the client console from a react component?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, console

I do not know if I gave myself to understand for example in the file **server / main.js** place something like this

```
Meteor.startup (() => {
     console.log ('where am I');
     // example of collection and map
   });
```

and you can see the message but within an extended react component how can I do it or would I have to import some method?

Comment: How can you do what? Print something on the client console?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log` in client side code too. Stick `console.log` at the top of your `render()` function if you'd like and you'll see a message in the web browser's console.